# Profinite group, and why the product of subgroups is closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, profinite-groups

The following lemma is taken from Wilson's book Profinite Groups;

> Let $( H_i : i \in I)$ be a family of normal subgroups of a profinite
>   group $G$.
>
> Assume $G = \overline{< \cup_{i \in I} H_i >}$, and write $K_i = 
>  \overline{< \cup_{j \neq i } H_j >}$.
>
> Moreover assume that $\cap_{i \in I}K_i = \{e\}$.
>
> Then $G = \prod H_i$.

He starts the proof by noting:

1. $K_i \cap H_i = \{e\}$ which follows by the assumptions above.
2. $K_i \triangleleft G$ which follows because $< \cup_{i \in I} H_i >$ is normal, and the closure of a normal subgroup is normal.
3. $K_iH_i$ is closed.

Why does 3. follow? I know that if $H_i$ was closed then it would follow directly because in a hausdorff, compact group $G$, $C,D$ closed implies that $CD$ is too.

Comment: He does write in the beginning of the chapter that when he writes $H \leq G$ he means that $H$ is closed as well. But the notation isn't used here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely it is intended to be assumed that the $H_i$ are closed.  Indeed, the result is not true otherwise.  For instance, you could take $I$ to be a singleton and the only $H$ to be a dense normal subgroup and then the result would claim that $G=H$, which certainly does not need to be true in general.